# Laravel: Forms on pages with url parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a routes generated as below and want to put a form on the page:

```
Route::get('suppliers/dashboards/{supplier}', ['uses'=>'SuppliersDashInvoiceController@index'])->middleware('auth');

Route::post('suppliers/dashboards/{supplier}', array( 'before' => 'csrf', 'uses' => 'SuppliersDashInvoiceController@iprocess'))->middleware('auth');
```

But when using the Form laravel helper, I get an error relating to

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: ] [URI: suppliers/dashboards/{supplier}]
```

Form helper:

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => array('SuppliersDashInvoiceController@iprocess'))) !!}
```

Does anyone know how to pass the `{supplier}` parameter to the form open helper, its not documented in the laravel docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass parameter, for example:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['SuppliersDashInvoiceController@iprocess', $supplier->id]]) !!}
```

https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#opening-a-form

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will accept the answer shortly.